# print range of numbers incrementing every fourth time

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

i have a range of numbers from 1 to 4, i have the following code to print them in sequence:

```
count = 1
while count <= 4:
  print(count)
  count += 1
```

My desired final output is this, how can i achieve this?

```
1:0
1:1
1:2
1:3
2:0
2:1
2:2
2:3
3:0
3:1
3:2
3:3
4:0
4:1
4:2
4:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested loop:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(4):
        print '{}:{}'.format(i, j) 

1:0
1:1
1:2
1:3
2:0
2:1
2:2
2:3
3:0
3:1
3:2
3:3
4:0
4:1
4:2
4:3
```